# Как создать поток?

Tags: c++, linux

Такой вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

void* helloWorld(void *args)
{
    cout << "Hello from thread!\n";
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, helloWorld, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

> undefined reference to `pthread_create'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Не понимаю причину их появления.

Comment: Это не "код выдаёт ошибки", а компилятору не сказано линковать с библиотекой `libpthread`.

Comment: Если у Вас g++, то просто добавьте `-pthread` к ключам компиляции -- `g++ -pthread t.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

Не подключена соответствующая библиотека.

Но если вы работаете с C++ - почему бы не воспользоваться стандартными средствами? `std::thread`, `std::async`?

Comment: А в крестах уже все, что есть в `pthread_...` реализовали?

Comment: @avp Во-первых, вряд ли на этом уровне - когда вопрос о подключении библиотеки встает - нужна какая-то особая функциональность, во-вторых, стандарт - он и есть стандарт, а в третьих, никто не мешает получить дескриптор потока и делать с ним все, что душе угодно.

Comment: @avp, а чего нет в C++, что есть в pthread?